# Find the number of "p-safe numbers"

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> For a positive integer $p$, define the positive integer $n$ to be $p$-safe if $n$ differs in absolute value by more than $2$ from all multiples of $p$. For example, the set of $10$-safe numbers is {${3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,23, ... }$}. Find the number of positive integers less than or equal to $10,000$ which are simultaneously $7$-safe, $11$-safe, and $13$-safe.

Obviously this has a lot to do with Modular Arithmetic and CRT.

For example from 0-14 (7-safe)

$3, 4, 10, 11$ It follows that:

> $N \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ **or** $N \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$ same for negative.

For $0-22$ (11-safe)

$3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19$ It follows,

> $N \equiv 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \pmod{11}$.

For $0-26$ (13-safe)

$3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23$ It follows,

> $N \equiv 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \pmod{13}$

Now, all I need is some **hints on how I can find the number of $N$ solutions? Just hints, nothing else, thanks!**

Comment: Seing as $7\cdot 11\cdot 13 = 1001$, I would find the answer for $1001$ first, and then just multiply. Also, note that $7,11$ and $13$ are all relatively prime, which should help with that calculation.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem would be handy.

Comment: @Arthur, what would multiplication do though?

Comment: The solution is 958.

Comment: @Columbo, thanks but I need to know how to get there.

Comment: Multiplication would help in this way: Since $1001$ is divisible by both $7, 11$ and $13$, the pattern of numbers that you're after (numbers that are both $7$-safe, $11$-safe and $13$-safe) will repeat with period $1001$. That means there are exactly as many between $0$ and $1001$ as there are between $1001$ and $2002$. And so on, up to $10,010$. That means that if you know how many there are below $1001$, you can just multiply by $10$, and you get how many there are  below $10,010$. Now, to get to $10,000$, you just have to check those ten specific numbers for safety.

Comment: @Arthur, wait wow, hold on a second, I need to swallow that. Okay so $1001$ is divisible by $7, 11, 13$ but how does that tell you the period and everything else? Also how does it give exactly the numbers that are all three 7,11, 13 safe? <-- How do you derive this fact?

Comment: The rest of a division by either 7, 11 or 13 does not change if you add 1001 to the dividend.

Comment: @Amad27 Well, it gives you the answer for $10,010$ very quickly once you know the answer for $1001$. To get the answer for $1001$, though, you need something else. That's where the real work lies.  
The main point of my previous comment is that if $n$ is a good number, then $n+1001, n+2002, n+3003$ and so on are also good numbers. Since $1001$ is divisible by all three of $7,11,13$, adding $1001$ doesn't ever change neither $7$-safety, $11$-safety nor $13$-safety. Therefore you can focus on counting the safe numbers below $1001$.

Comment: @Arthur, but how do you know the cycle is $1001$?

Comment: @Amad27 Because $1001 = 7\cdot 11\cdot 13$. Whether a number is good or not is based solely on how far away it is from numbers that are divisible by $7$, $11$ or $13$. Numbers that are divisible by either of these three numbers appear in a periodic pattern on the number line, and the length of that repeating pattern is $1001$, because that's the first place (after $0$) where the three sequences $(0, 7,14,21,28,\ldots)$, $(0, 11, 22, 33, 44,\ldots)$ and $(0, 13, 26, 39, 52, \ldots)$ join up.

Comment: @Arthur, is it possible to show this using modular arithemetic? It would be easier

Comment: @Amad27 $1001 \equiv 0 \pmod{7.11.13}$?

Comment: Whether a number is good or not is solely dependent on its residue modulo $1001$. Which means that for every good number between $0$ and $1001$, there are exactly _ten_ good numbers between $0$ and $10,010$.

Comment: Yes, I understood Please confirm: There are $x$ combined good numbers from 0 to 1001 (which is one complete divisibility set after $0$). Then to $2002$ $3003$ etc... But it is still very tough finding from $0 \to 1001$

Comment: @Arthur, can you advice me on how to find p-safe from 0 to 1001, brute fforce takes toolong. Just some hints please

Comment: This is where it comes in handy that the numbers are coprime. First of all, I hope that you can see that the number of $7$-safe numbers below $1001$ is $1001\cdot2/7$, since $7$-safeness is only dependent on residue modulo $7$. Now, since $7$ and $11$ are coprime, we have that there are $1001\cdot2/7\cdot6/11$ numbers that are both $7$-safe and $11$-safe. (Again, look what happens modulo $77$.) Can you figure out the answer for the last one?

Comment: @Arthur, how about CRT? If $N \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$ and $N \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$ and $N \equiv 5 \pmod{13}$ for example, we can find an $N$ that satisfies all by $N \equiv x_1 \pmod{1001}$. Same goes for all other combinations such as $(3, 5, 4)$ or $(3, 5, 6)$ or something right? So $96$ numbers in $[0, 1001]$. ?

Comment: That's a valid solution as well.